# Clojure zippers path function not complete?

Tags: clojure, zipper

**EDIT #2:** This entire question and exploration were based on my missing the fundamental notion of zippers; that they represent a perspective in a datastructure from the point of view of a particular node. So a zipper is - at all times - a pair of the current node and what the rest of the tree looks like from the perspective of that node. I was originally trying to generate a whole new structure from the zipper, while the zipper itself was all I needed, all along. I'll leave this all up for posterity, in the hope that somebody else is helped by it (or so it serves as a warning to any successors!).

Original question:

I'm trying to get my head around using zippers to manipulate trees. The specific problem is that I need to generate at runtime routes between two nodes matching arbitrary criteria in an arbitrary tree.

I thought I could use the `path` function to get a route to a location by calling `path` on the current location. But the path returned seems to omit the last step(s) required to get there.

For example:

```
(def test-zip (vector-zip [0 [1] [2 [3 [4] 5 [6 [7] [8]]]]]))
(-> test-zip 
    down right right down 
    right down right right
    node)
```

gives `5`, but

```
(-> test-zip 
    down right right down 
    right down right right
    path)
```

gives

```
[[0 [1] [2 [3 [4] 5 [6 [7] [8]]]]] [2 [3 [4] 5 [6 [7] [8]]]] [3 [4] 5 [6 [7] [8]]]]
```

which isn't the same location (it's missing the effect of the last three steps, `down right right`).

It looks like the path function only gets you to the parent location in the tree, ignoring any siblings between you and the actual location.

Am I missing the point of the `path` function? I'd assumed that given a tree and a path, applying the path to the tree would bring you to the original location of the path, not partly there.

**UPDATE**: I've used the following function definition to compile a path of nodes from a start location to an end location:

```
(defn lca-path [start-loc end-loc]
  (let [sczip (z/root start-loc)
        start-path (z/path start-loc)
        start-node (z/node start-loc)
        end-path (z/path end-loc)
        end-node (z/node end-loc)
        lca-path (filter (set start-path) end-path)
        lca-node [(last lca-path)]
        lca-to-start (conj (vec (drop (count lca-path) start-path)) start-node)
        lca-to-end (conj (vec (drop (count lca-path) end-path)) end-node)
        ]

    (concat (reverse lca-to-start) lca-node lca-to-end))
  )
```

Pretty heavily influenced by the chat with @Mark Fisher, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think you're right, it's the parent it paths to, and this is confirmed looking [at this site](http://www.exampler.com/blog/2010/09/01/editing-trees-in-clojure-with-clojurezip/), `path` returns "all subtrees from the root of the tree down to just above the current loc".

For your structure, the tree is:

```
   A
 / | \
0  o  B
   | / \
   1 2  C __
       /|\  \
      3 o 5  o
        |   /|\
        4  6 o o
             | |
             7 8
```

So the 3 nodes marked A, B, C are the parent nodes what lead to the parent of 5, which are:

```
A: [0 [1] [2 [3 [4] 5 [6 [7] [8]]]]]
B: [2 [3 [4] 5 [6 [7] [8]]]]
C: [3 [4] 5 [6 [7] [8]]]
```

which is the result you're getting.

EDIT: I created this function to search between two values in a vector and return the `path` between them. Does this help? I'm not an expert on zippers so this is learning for me too.

```
(defn between [v s e]
  (let [zv (zip/vector-zip v)
        find-loc (fn [zv l]
                   (loop [loc zv]
                     (if (= l (zip/node loc))
                       loc 
                       (if (zip/end? loc)
                           nil
                           (recur (zip/next loc))))))
        sv (zip/vector-zip (-> (find-loc zv s) zip/up zip/node))
        e-in-sv (find-loc sv e)
        path-s-e (when (some? e-in-sv)
                   (zip/path e-in-sv))]
    path-s-e))
```

It finds the path between the parent of the start value and parent of end value, and you can use it like:

```
(def sov [0 [1] [2 [3 [4] 5 [6 [7] [8]]]]])
(between sov 2 6)
=> [[2 [3 [4] 5 [6 [7] [8]]]] [3 [4] 5 [6 [7] [8]]] [6 [7] [8]]]
```

I'm walking the tree to find the parent of the starting value, and then create a new zipper from its parent so that the path is limited from start point. The helper function "find-loc" returns a zipper for the entry you're looking for, e.g. "5" within a vector. `sv` is then the parent vector containing the start value.

Where there is no path it returns nil, e.g. between 1 and 4 you'd have to traverse up 2 elements.

This was in response to your comments of having to find the value in the final node (e.g. `5` in `[3 [4] 5 [6 [7] [8]]]`), which i don't think you need to do, but without the real example of what you're doing is difficult to comment on.

BTW, there may be much better ways of traverse/finding values in the vector than the custom function, but as I say zippers are pretty new for me too.

Comment: So once you get to the parent subtree, you have to search for the required node manually in the immediate descendants of the last sub-tree? Given that the immediately descending nodes are `3`. `[4]`, `5` and `[6 [7] [8]]` that's not too wide a search in this case. But is it not strange that the same path is returned for all four locations? Is there some other idiomatic way of capturing the route to a location in a zipper I'm missing?

Comment: I'm kind of sharing the journey with you on this one. I've updated my answer to include a finder over your vector between 2 points. Does this fit what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Also I think it's this way because you're using simple vector-zips rather than some custom zipper over your data.

Comment: Doesn't this duplicate the functionality of the `path` function? Once you find the start location and end location, and call path on both of those, you can do `(filter (set start-path) end-path)` to get the lowest common ancestor of both points. I also do 

`lca-to-start-parent (drop (count lca-loc) start-path)`

to get the path from the lowest common ancestor to the start point, and 

`(drop (count lca-loc) end-path)` 

for the other leg to the end point. 

I like the self-contained implementation you have, and how you could use identical? to navigate to the parent location...

Comment: Just saw your next comment - I'm actually using vectors as a simplified example to get to grips with zippers, I'm using a custom zipper for my actual data but wanted to rule it out as a complicating factor

Comment: possibly yes! I was trying to get a better understanding of your problem myself and thought i'd share. there's a good section in Clojure Programming on pathing between 2 points in a maze using a custom zipper using path (http://www.clojurebook.com/). I think the nature of your question of there being the same path to a same number of elements is more a property of using vector-zippers rather than it being a general issue with zippers.... and this comment crossed with your comment :)

Comment: Probably worth noting too that we're both assuming unique values for nodes (true in my case)